# Python dictionary manipulation

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I got a list of object

```
lst = [1,2,3]
```

I want them in a dictionary with a default key 'number', and then put them in a list.

The result should look like

```
lst = [{'number':1},{'number':2},{'number':3}
```

Use less code, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches your code samples:

```
>>> lst = [1,2,3]
>>> newlst = [dict(number=n) for n in lst]
>>> newlst
[{'number': 1}, {'number': 2}, {'number': 3}]
>>>
```

What you *say*, however, is a bit different - you want them all in the *same* dictionary, or each in a dictionary of its own? The snippet above gives you the latter.

Answer (score 7):

Use a list comprehension

```
lst = [{'number': x} for x in lst]
```